# How to Search Specific Subject, find, & reply all?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

I need to search the inbox, sent, draft, & outbox, for the latest message containing a particular Subject line & reply all. (Trying to continue the threads of specific emails.)

Posted on other sites, however I have not received any actionable advice.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to search for items in a single folder. But the most powerful and reliable search is using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class.

The key benefits of using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

One of your links leads to the code you are interested in:

```
Option Explicit

' Event handler for outlook
Dim WithEvents OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookSearch As Outlook.Search
Dim outlookResults As Outlook.Results

Dim searchComplete As Boolean


' Handler for Advanced search complete
Private Sub outlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
    'MsgBox "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired."
    searchComplete = True
End Sub


Sub SearchAndReply(emailSubject As String, searchFolderName As String, searchSubFolders As Boolean)

    ' Declare objects variables
    Dim customMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim resultItem As Integer

    ' Variable defined at the class level
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    ' Variable defined at the class level (modified by outlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete when search is completed)
    searchComplete = False

    ' You can look up on the internet for urn:schemas strings to make custom searches
    searchString = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject like '" & emailSubject & "'" ' Use: subject like '%" & emailSubject & "%'" if you want to include words see %

    ' Perform advanced search
    Set outlookSearch = OutlookApp.AdvancedSearch(searchFolderName, searchString, searchSubFolders, "SearchTag")

    ' Wait until search is complete based on outlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete event
    While searchComplete = False
        DoEvents
    Wend

    ' Get the results
    Set outlookResults = outlookSearch.Results

    If outlookResults.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ' Sort descending so you get the latest
    outlookResults.Sort "[SentOn]", True

    ' Reply only to the latest one
    resultItem = 1

    ' Some properties you can check from the email item for debugging purposes
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print outlookResults.Item(resultItem).SentOn, outlookResults.Item(resultItem).ReceivedTime, outlookResults.Item(resultItem).SenderName, outlookResults.Item(resultItem).Subject
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set customMailItem = outlookResults.Item(resultItem).ReplyAll

    ' At least one reply setting is required in order to replyall to fire
    customMailItem.Body = "Just a reply text " & customMailItem.Body

    customMailItem.Display

End Sub
```

You may find the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the direction!
To clarify, I simply need to copy & paste the above code but change:
& emailSubject &
To whatever need be searched & replied to?